# How to commit a folder and open a Pull Request via Github API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, github, github-api

I want to commit a pipeline config for a user via the Github API.

So far I am able to commit just a file named `main.yaml` into the root directory of the repo but I need the file to sit within `.github/workflows/main.yaml`.

The code I have so far is this:

```
const commitWorkflowConfig = async ({
  ownerName,
  repoName
}) => {

  const pipelineConfig = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../../templates/main.yaml', { encoding: "utf-8" })

  // Create Blob from the content
  const blob = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/blobs`, {
    content: pipelineConfig,
    encoding: "utf-8"
  })

  // Get last commit hash of Master
  const {
    commit: {
      sha: masterSha
    }
  } = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/branches/master`)

  // Create new branch from master
  const branch = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/refs`, 
  {
    "ref": "refs/heads/workflow-pipeline",
    "sha": masterSha
  })

  // Create commit to new branch
  const commit = await axios.put(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/contents/main.yaml`, {
    message: "New commit",
    content: pipelineConfig,
    sha: blob.sha,
    branch: "workflow-pipeline"
  })

  // Open Pull Request
  const response = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/pulls`, {
    title: "New PR",
    head: "workflow-pipeline",
    base: "master"
  })
  
}    const commitWorkflowConfig = async ({
  ownerName,
  repoName
}) => {

  const pipelineConfig = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../../templates/main.yaml', { encoding: "utf-8" })

  // Create Blob from the content
  const blob = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/blobs`, {
    content: pipelineConfig,
    encoding: "utf-8"
  })

  // Get last commit hash of Master
  const {
    commit: {
      sha: masterSha
    }
  } = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/branches/master`)

  // Create new branch from master
  const branch = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/refs`, 
  {
    "ref": "refs/heads/workflow-pipeline",
    "sha": masterSha
  })

  // Create commit to new branch
  const commit = await axios.put(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/contents/main.yaml`, {
    message: "New commit",
    content: pipelineConfig,
    sha: blob.sha,
    branch: "workflow-pipeline"
  })

  // Open Pull Request
  const response = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/pulls`, {
    title: "New PR",
    head: "workflow-pipeline",
    base: "master"
  })
  
}
```

This feels like a lot of API calls all for just committing one file and opening a PR, I suspect I am doing something wrong?

When I create the new commit, it doesn't allow me to add any path or add `.github/workflows/main.yaml` to the end of the URL as I get a 404. Is there any way I can update this commit to commit to a folder instead of the root directory?

To summarise, How can I make a simple commit of `.github/workflows/main.yaml` to a new branch and open a PR for it?

### Create tree example:

```
const tree = await this.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
  base_tree: masterSha,
  tree: [
    {
      path: ".github",
      mode: "040000",
      type: "tree"
    },
    {
      path: ".github/workflow",
      mode: "040000",
      type: "tree"
    },
    {
      path: ".github/workflow/main.yaml",
      mode: "100755",
      type: "tree",
      content: pipelineConfig
    },
  ]
})
```

#### Creating the tree

```
const { tree } = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
  base_tree: masterSha,
  tree: [
    {
      path: "workflows/main.yaml",
      mode: "100644", 
      type: "blob",
      sha
    }
  ]
})

const workflowTree = tree.find(t => t.path === "workflows");

await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
  base_tree: masterSha,
  tree: [
    {
      path: ".github/workflows",
      mode: workflowTree.mode, // "040000"
      type: workflowTree.type, // "tree"
      sha: workflowTree.sha 
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: "This feels like a lot of API calls all for just committing one file and opening a PR". I also felt that way when I used the GitHub API. An alternative is to just spawn `git` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The following code does *not* use the GitHub API properly

```js
// Create commit to new branch
  const commit = await axios.put(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/contents/main.yaml`, {
    message: "New commit",
    content: pipelineConfig,
    sha: blob.sha,
    branch: "workflow-pipeline"
  })
```

You cannot directly edit the contents of a file. You need to use the trees API to create an entirely new tree based off of the original tree.

### Steps

1. Create the blob for the new file (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-blob). You already did this step good job.
2. Get the tree that you want to make your new branch based off of (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-branch). Note that you have to get the *tree sha*, not the *commit sha*.
3. Create a new tree with that file added (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree). I think this step will be the most complicated, because for each 'folder' tree created, a parent 'folder' tree will also need to be created to contain the newly created 'folder' tree. So if you want to modify the `.github/workflows` folder, you'll first have to create a new tree based on`.github/workflows`. Let's say that tree sha was `abc...`. Then you'll need to create a new tree based on the `.github` folder, and make the `workflows` dir `abc...`, and not the old one.
4. Create a commit (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-commit). Use the sha of the root tree you created in the previous step.
5. Create a new branch (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference). In the question code, you created it *before* you created the commit, which doesn't make sense. You need to create it *after* you create the commit, so that it's head will point to the sha of the commit you created.
6. Create the pull request (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request). You already have this step in your code.

Here is a visual that explains the steps 2 and 3 for adding a `main.yml` file to `.github/workflows`:

```
Original tree        | New Tree (but the '.github' tree references ^b, not b)
- sha: a           --> - sha: ^a
- files:               - files:
  - .github        -->   - .github (but the 'workflows' tree references ^c, not c)
    - sha: b               - sha: ^b
    - files:               - files
      - workflows  -->       - workflows (but with the main.yml)
        - sha: c               - sha: ^c
        - files:               - files:
                                 - main.yml (reference the sha of the blob you created)
          ...
      ...
  ...
```

There are three `-->`s in the visual. Each `-->` is a request to make.

1. Start with creating the `^c` tree, which is based off of the `c` tree and has the added `main.yml` file.
2. Create the `^b` tree, which is based off of `b` but has `^c` in it.
3. Create the `^a` tree, which is based off of `a` but has `^b` in it.

And those are the steps to creating a <strike>simple</strike> simple, but complicated to create pull request.

It's surprising how many API calls are needed for this. 5 + {how deep the file you want to add is}

Comment: Ok that flow makes sense. Regarding creating the tree, I have added an example snippet to my orginal post but is it correct to have my base_tree as my master SHA hash? And what looks as though I need to include a sha or contents for each tree object. What would I use for these values in the subdirectory trees?

Comment: You're almost right with the base_tree. Just use the *tree hash* instead of the *commit hash*. I updated the answer to include the step of getting the base tree sha.

Comment: I noticed that you used `path: ".github/workflow/main.yaml"` when creating a tree. I think that you can only create one 'folder' at a time, but if your method works, then tell me so that I can update the answer to use your method.

Comment: My method doesn't work. I think you're right, can only create one folder at a time

Comment: So does that mean I have to make 2 api calls to `/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`? One to create the directory and one to create the file? What would the sha or content field in the payload be for an empty directory?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain creating the trees more.

Comment: To create an empty directory, make the `tree` field `[]`, so that it has no items. Except  creating an empty directory isn't useful, because git doesn't care about empty directories. To remove a file, just use `null` instead of a hash.

Comment: Thanks so much. Finally got it working. I have added the code example to my original post. Your diagram of the trees was very useful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, I am working on the same topic where I need to update files inside `.github/workflows` folder by API and, I think I found a better and easy way.

I don't know since when but, with this endpoint https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents with the right permissions (scope `workflow` in your authToken), you can create and update files into the `.github/workflows` folder.

```js
// to create a new file
await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world',
  path: '.github/workflows/your-file.yml',
  message: 'Your commit message',
  content: 'contentInBase64'
});

// to update a file

// get the sha of the file that you want to update
const { 
  data: contentData 
} = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world',
  path: '.github/workflows/your-file.yml',
});

const shaOfCurrentFileToUpdate = contentData.sha;

await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world',
  path: '.github/workflows/your-file.yml',
  message: 'Your new commit message',
  content: 'newContentInBase64'
  sha: shaOfCurrentFileToUpdate
});
```

With this, I removed a lot of lines of code and solved the issue on my side, I hope is helpful for you too.